# Download CSV from ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, download

I'm posting json to my server and I want to return a csv response and have my browser automatically download the csv.

I know there have been some questions on SO exactly about this topic on the past. So far, I've gathered the following solutions:

1. Put the request into  `<form>` element. This isn't possible because the JSON is nested and too large to be posted as a string.
2. Save the csv file (get request) onto the server and then have a separate post request to download it. This is not ideal because I don't want to keep a bunch of useless csv files on my server.

Is there a better solution? Can I make a Post request act like a form submission and automatically get the file to start downloading?

Comment: Yes. Post the json data and have the server return the csv file in response. Do you not have control over how the post operation is handled in the server-side code?